# How do I return a default value if collection is empty?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

(`Fees` is a collection of `Fee` objects.)

If the Fees collection is empty, I want to assign a default value of `0` to `FeeValue`.

Below is what I currently do.  However, I'd prefer to not *new* up an instance of Fee.  What are some alternative ways to write this?  Thanks!

```cs
from w in Widgets
select new {
  FeeValue = w.Fees.DefaultIfEmpty(new Fee()).First().Value, // Value is a Double
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your questions is a bit confusing, but I think I know what you're asking...

Something like this:

```
Widgets
    .Select(w => 
        new 
        {
            FeeValue = w.Fees.Select(f => f.Value).DefaultIfEmpty(yourDefaultValue)
        });
```

Comment: You got the right idea. To work, I needed to make it like this:  `FeeValue = w.Fees.Select(f => f.Value).DefaultIfEmpty(0).First()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the empty Select() this should work as well:

```
Widgets
.Select(w => 
    new 
    {
        FeeValue = w.Fees.DefaultIfEmpty(yourDefaultValue).First()
    });
```

Comment: Fees is a collection of Fee objects.  Sorry for not making that clearer.  I need the property "Value" to be returned if not null. So I'd have to alter this answer to be:  `w.Fees.DefaultIfEmpty(new Fee()).First().Value` ... which matches my original attempt.